# How to loop on one table to update another

Tags: sql-server

I need to loop on records in one table and then update another table.
But for some reason I cannot get it working.

```
DECLARE @v_id1 char(10);
DECLARE @v_id2 char(10);

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT table1.id1, table1.id2 FROM table1;

OPEN cursor1;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @v_id1, @v_id2;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    UPDATE table2 
    SET table2.record_status = TRIM(table2.record_status)+'OK' 
    WHERE table2.id1 = @v_id1 AND table2.id2 = @v_id2;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @v_id1, @v_id2;
END

CLOSE cursor1;
DEALLOCATE cursor1;
```

I would also like to know how to reference the fields in table1 without having to create two variables.

When I try using table1.id1 in the UPDATE WHERE, I get a bound error (The multi-part identifier... could not be bound).

I also tried an example from another post, but got the bound error:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET status_record='OK'
SELECT id1, id2 FROM Table2
WHERE Table1.id1 = Table2.id1 AND Table1.id2 = Table2.id2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Quote both exact errors, please.

Comment: There is an [example in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#OtherTables) regarding updating a table with the content of another table. Take a look and adapt it to your schema.

Comment: It works when I do it like this:

UPDATE Table1 SET record_status = TRIM(record_status)+'OK' 
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2
ON t2.id1 = t1.id1 AND t2.id2 = t1.id2;

But the moment I add CHARINDEX it does not work. Why?

AND CHARINDEX('OK',t1.record_status)=0;

Comment: In other words, I only want to UPDATE if OK does not already exist in record_status. But my use of CHARINDEX does not seem to allow me to do this. How can I do this?

Comment: @jack_humphrey - Works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e353e0/1 Your data must be different to what you think. Or check your collation settings

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
UPDATE t2
SET 
    record_status = TRIM(t2.record_status) + 'OK' 
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1
ON t2.Id1 = t1.Id1
AND t2.Id2 = t1.Id2
```